# Gpuarray in Cuda/Matlab

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu

I want to know if there is a way to optimize the matlab function `gather`. I am developing a Cuda code with very huge matrices and I have noticed that the `gather` function that I have to use to get back my GPU data is quite slow. For a 2^13x2^8 matrix, it takes about 3 seconds!

Comment: @MariusBrendmoe, [gather](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gather.html) is the function within matlab to move a gpuArray type back from device memory to host memory. There aren't necessarily any user-defined kernels in matlab GPU code.

Comment: Hello, I am using a GTX 680 card. And my matrix contains single (float in cuda) values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of `gpuArray.gather` is limited by your PCI bus. You can optimise this only by gathering less data (e.g. using indexing). Note that in more recent versions of Parallel Computing Toolbox, many of the operations are asynchronous, but `gather` is not - so perhaps you are simply seeing the time for the asynchronous requests to complete. You can check using `wait(gpuDevice)` to synchronize the device.

Comment: I haven't benchmarked `gpuArray.gather`, but doing some rough math, an array of 2^21 floats or doubles should be about 16 or 32MB, I think.  This shouldn't take anywhere near 3 seconds to transfer, so I think the suggestion of synchronizing before doing any timing measurement is a very good one to investigate -- this is a common timing mistake on non-matlab GPU code anyway.  I did do some timing of gpuArray matrix multiply quite a while ago, it must have been before matlab exposed the operation as asynchronous, because I just used tic and toc around the multiply.